# Get a list of all underlying ids from an Enum C#

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum :

```
public enum Handlers
{
     OnEditProfile = 6100,
     OnResetAllIns = 6103,
     OnHandHistory = 6104,
     OnTransHistory = 6105,
     OnChangeEmail = 6106,
     OnValidateEmailThroughGameServer = 6107
}
```

I want to get a list if all underlying ids so the end result to be something like this:

```
var allIntegers = new List<int>()
{
     6100,
     6103,
     6104,
     6105,
     6106,
     6107
};
```

I went through enum methods, but couldn't find anytihg that will do the job. Thanks!

EDIT:

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(Handlers)).Cast<int>().ToList();
```

This look like the best solution for me, but for some reason I cannot `.Cast<int>().ToList()`. I am using .Net Framework 4.0 if it does matter in this case.

Comment: Have a look at [Enum.GetValues()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx).

Comment: You should really accept @Boluc Papuccuoglu's answer since with it you get int list as you asked

Comment: @Antonio Bakula - Take a look at my edit. Sure his solution looks the best, but for some reason it does not work for me. I cannot Cast to int. Any suggestion about this are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: @Mdb maybe you just need to add System.Linq to uses clause

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(Handlers)).Cast<int>().ToList();
```

Comment: Beat me to it but you are the winner for casting it to a list as required :D

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this in one line.

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(Handlers)).Cast<int>();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use [Enum.GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx) :

```
foreach (Handlers handler in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Handlers)))
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(Handlers));
```

[Read more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Handlers)).Cast<int>().ToList();
```